# Возникает ошибка при открытии приложения на Android 7.0

Tags: java, android

> **java.lang.RuntimeException:**
>
> at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity
>   (ActivityThread.java:2584)
>
> at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity
>   (ActivityThread.java:2666)
>
> at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11 (ActivityThread.java)   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1493)
>
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:111)
>
> at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:207)
>
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:5769)
>
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
>
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run
>   (ZygoteInit.java:789)
>
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:679)
>
> Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException:    at
>   android.app.ActivityManager$TaskDescription. 
>   (ActivityManager.java:600)   at
>   android.app.Activity.onApplyThemeResource (Activity.java:3794)
>
> at android.view.ContextThemeWrapper.initializeTheme
>   (ContextThemeWrapper.java:150)
>
> at android.view.ContextThemeWrapper.setTheme
>   (ContextThemeWrapper.java:94)
>
> at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setTheme
>   (AppCompatActivity.java:90)
>
> at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity
>   (ActivityThread.java:2524)

Не могу понять в чём именно ошибка. Google не помог.

Comment: Приведите полный стектрейс. Из этого куска ничего не понять.

Comment: Это всё что есть в Play Console.http://prntscr.com/n3j1g8

Comment: Здесь нет ни строчки вашего кода. Либо баг в Support Library, либо прошивки телефона. Если случай единичный, игнорируйте.

Comment: Как вариант, проверьте если приложение работает корректно на Android 6.

Comment: Android 5.1 тоже ошибка такая же. Приложение не открывается. **Здесь нет ни строчки вашего кода** знал бы откуда предоставить, то предоставил бы

Comment: Может ли это быть связано с SharedPreferences? До использования SharedPreferences проблем не было.

Comment: <<знал бы откуда предоставить, то предоставил бы>> - попробуйте пройтись отладчиком по программе и, думаю, скорее всего Вы найдёте, где она падает.

Comment: Про строчки кода, я имел ввиду стектрейс. Тут наблюдается проблема с темой приложения, отсюда надо начать копать, судя по `android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setTheme()`.

Comment: Если падает на эмуляторе или доступном девайсе, приведите стектрейс из logcat.